# Iron particles around a magnet

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

There are some iron particles on a board. We pass a current carrying wire through that board and the particles form circles. Show these circles if input given is the position of the wire.

Consider the board to be a grid of size 7x7 (fixed)

No extra white spaces are allowed.

Input can be 0-indexed or 1-indexed. (0-indexed in examples)

#### Examples

```
input:3,3 # 'X' is wire here but can be shown by anything other than '\/|-'
output:
/-----\
|/---\|
||/-\||
|||X|||
||\-/||
|\---/|
\-----/

input:1,2
output:
|/-\|||
||X||||
|\-/|||
\---/||
-----/|
------/
-------

input:0,0
output:
X||||||
-/|||||
--/||||
---/|||
----/||
-----/|
------/

input:0,3
output:
|||X|||
||\-/||
|\---/|
\-----/
-------
-------
-------

input:3,0
output:
---\|||
--\||||
-\|||||
X||||||
-/|||||
--/||||
---/|||
```

This is **code-golf** so shortest code wins.

Comment: Can the function output a 7x7 matrix with the characters or we need to print it on the console ?

Answer (score 7):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 40 bytes

```
7 7{.6 6&-|.0":<^:6@8[9!:7@'/_\___\_/|-'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT8Fcwbxaz0zBTE23Rs9AycomzsrMwSLaUtHK3EFdPz4mPh6I9Wt01f@nJmfkK6Q52CkYKBhYKwB1WCsYKhhZA7nG1grGCgb/AQ)

Comment: Neat use of box drawing once again! Can you provide an axplanation of the entire solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>136</s> <s>119</s> 116 bytes

```r
function(i,j,m=diag(7),R=row(m)-i,a=j-col(m)){m[]='-'
m[R==a]='\\'
m[R==-a]='/'
m[R<a&R>-a|R>a&-R>a]='|'
m[i,j]=0
m}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU/NjsIgEL7zFJNsIpAM2a2aNTHibV@gemt7IJUqpoBpMTZZffYuxe6F72/gG7rxAwxeQXUaMmHcSQ/6RBo5NndXB@MdiylaeTLqzDYcc9n5B7NcGFTyKmrfRsF/bVFJKiixRS6lirwsZyEm9ZnETi3yvVDPfK8WIh4xeE5BbKjkF7GvMeg@9LAT0Jo@MFKzNa45RlziKmGG2Yxv/xuXCVe44YQTUqvA6OHiH6Ac6EHZW6vBNxAuETpzNk614O/hdg9gVejMAI3voEkFsC0d5eQtCCExYQ6Mg2zbancOF5b2i98lABOdNk1WUbiqimaqL93x53AEig4pMIrTRJFVSHHmy8h5rMJe3ySNjQB2mN5q2P/sPDdFj84EzQKzA8cMN9inKy8y/gE)

- -3 bytes saved thanks to @Giuseppe

Function that takes (row,col) coordinates of the wire (1-indexed) and returns a 7x7 matrix with the characters.

Answer (score 4):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>27</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 21 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
-７×［\＋］↶ω⟳ｎ↔┼⁷⁸╵７７＠↕↔
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=LSV1RkYxNyVENyV1RkYzQiU1QyV1RkYwQiV1RkYzRCV1MjFCNiV1MDNDOSV1MjdGMyV1RkY0RSV1MjE5NCV1MjUzQyV1MjA3NyV1MjA3OCV1MjU3NSV1RkYxNyV1RkYxNyV1RkYyMCV1MjE5NSV1MjE5NA__,i=NCUwQTI_,v=8)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>105</s>  103 bytes

Takes input as `(y)(x)`, 0-indexed.

```javascript
Y=>X=>(g=x=>y<7?`/\\-|X
`[h=(X-x)**2,v=(Y-y)**2,x<7?h<v?2:h>v?3:h?x<X^y<Y:4:5]+g(x<7?x+1:!++y):'')(y=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYvfCoIwHEbvfYuu3M@18k8RjG2@xiQLw9QV4iJjbNC7L/MuDM7Fx@F894u5jPXz9niRQV8b33JfcCG5QB23XDh2yKttWZK3DKqj4kgSC1GUrg1HBXHztFOjmMlTqoTJM6pyy@TZsYLu6P6EO/QNLE7oCmMHNAwBOR6Dr/Uw6r7Z9LpDLcpgAoJfmQBKFzKGiT9yec/m0n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 90 bytes

```perl6
{<| v - \ X />[1+([-]($_>>.abs).sign||3+[*]($_).sign)for ^7-$^a X ^7-$^b].rotor(7)>>.join}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2qZGoUxBVyFGIUJB3y7aUFsjWjdWQyXezk4vMalYU684Mz2vpsZYO1oLJArha6blFynEmeuqxCUCdYEZSbF6Rfkl@UUa5ppAnVn5mXm1/9M0jHWMQdzixEprrjQNQx0jJJ6BjgEKD1mlMZLcfwA)

Anonymous code block that takes two numbers and returns a list of lines.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 105 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:[''.join(['/-|'[cmp(abs(i-x),abs(j-y))],'\X'[i==x]][i-x==y-j]for j in R)for i in R]
R=range(7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xDoMgFEV3vuJtQALW6tDEhNUPcGqCDFilhSga6yBJ/52KTue8e2/ylrB9Zl9EI9o46qnrNewsVBLjzM3WE4lv/Ifla1qI7r7E8p2yJI4HShXD7RNLK8SulDw6IQJ3yswrOLAeGprUnqpQI1bt3wN50NgPBmpyPKIVgrQZ08ZcybJav8GI4BRUk5KV9MCdFQk5yy@cYZmu@Ac)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＧL⁷-↙⁶X‖Ｂ↘¬‖Ｊ±Ｎ±ＮＴ⁷¦⁷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gP6cyPT9Pw8pHR8FcR0FJV0nTmiugKDOvRMPKJb88zyc1rURHwQwuqBQBUhCUmpaTmlziVFpSklqUllMJURuUmZ4BVGx1aA1CiQaQ6VWaWxCSr@GXmp5YkqrhmVdQWuJXmpuUWqShqamjgFUYqCukKDNXA@gkc03r//8NuUz@65blAAA) Takes 0-indexed column and row as input. Explanation:

```
ＧL⁷-
```

Draw a triangle of `-`s.

```
↙⁶
```

Draw a line along the hypotenuse. (This is the wrong way around but we'll fix that later.)

```
X
```

Draw the `X` that shows the position of the wire. (Any other ASCII character could be used here of course.) This completes one eighth of the drawing.

```
‖Ｂ↘¬
```

Reflect three times (`¬` = left + down) while transforming characters to almost complete the diagram.

```
‖
```

Reflect without transforming to switch the `/`s with the `\`s so they now point around the `X` instead of towards it.

```
Ｊ±Ｎ±Ｎ
```

Jump to the top left of the desired output.

```
Ｔ⁷¦⁷
```

Trim the result to the desired size.